# Show that the algebraic subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$ are just the finite subsets, together with $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$ itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, solution-verification, commutative-algebra

**Problem**: show that the algebraic subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$ are just the finite subsets, together with $\mathbb{A}^1(k)$ itself.

**My solution**: I'm self-teaching from an AG textbook so please bear with me, here's my best shot. Obviously the whole set counts because we have the trivial ideal generated by $(0)$, so $V((0))$ is the whole set. It would seem to me that given any finite subset $\{a_i\}$ of elements in $k$, I can give you a polynomial $p = \Pi_i (x - a_i)$ that trivially has that given subset of zeros. But clearly $(p)$ is not the ideal generating that set, since by the definition of an ideal, there would be other zeros floating around in there. So I thought, okay, imagine the natural homomorphism of rings $\pi : k[X] \to k[X]/(p)$. I suppose ker $\phi$ would be an ideal  such that $V(\ker \phi)$ is the required algebraic set. I suppose in this way I prove existence, but just not construction? (Obviously there can't be infinite such algebraic sets, since that would imply an infinite product of linear monomials, that part I feel like I get).

Am I on the right track?

TIA!

Comment: Fine up to "But clearly $(p)$..."

Comment: Are you saying that ideal does generate the algebraic set? It feels like it would include a whole bunch of other zeroes...

Comment: No, what I am saying is that before that point, you had successfully proved that $A^1$ and its finite subsets were algebraic subsets, but instead of embarking on the proof of the converse (that each algebraic subset apart from $A^1$ is finite) you went off at a bizarre tangent.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Agh, I see. I was confused about the relationship between ideals and varieties, thank you. So my polynomial and the ideal $I = (p)$ do in fact correspond to the set of points $\{a_i\}$ -- what remains then is to show that there is no proper subset that is infinite and an algebraic subset. It seems then it suffices to say that if we had such an infinite set $\{ b_i \}$, it would require at least one polynomial to exist such that $p(b_1,...)$, and each $(x - b_i)$ would have to divide it, so it would be the product of infinite linear monomials -- not defined/possible. QED?

Comment: Yeah, that idea works. To clean that up, you could say that you can continue to divide by $(x-b_i)$ indefinitely. But this contradicts that the process of dividing like this terminates (shown by induction on the degree of the polynomial).

Answer (score 7):

There is (in my opinion) a much simpler way of proving it:

Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^1_k$ be an algebraic set; i.e, $X=V(\mathfrak{a})$
for some ideal $\mathfrak{a} \subseteq k[x]$. Since $k[x]$ is a PID, there exists some polynomial $F \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}=(F)$. We distinguish two cases:

i) If $F=0$, then $\mathfrak{a}=\{0\}$ and $X=V(0)=\mathbb{A}^1_k$.

ii) If $F \neq 0$, then $F$ has a finite number of roots (possibly none if the field $k$ is not algebraically closed). Hence,
$$X=V(F)=\{p \in \mathbb{A}^1_k / F(p)=0\}=\{\text{roots of } F\}$$
is a finite set of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$.

Comment: Why do we have finite set in the first case?

Comment: @StojadinovicIsidora It is not finite (in general). The claim is that the closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ are the finite subsets and $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ itself.